# How to flip Image in silverlight from code behind

Tags: silverlight, asp.net-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I created a silverlight application. I want to flip an image, so i created a storyboard from code behind. But it's throwing an error **"Cannot resolve target name Imagename"**.

```
Storyboard sbFlip = new Storyboard();
          sbFlip.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
          DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames FlipFront = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
          DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames FlipBack = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
          Storyboard.SetTargetName(FlipFront, strFrontSelectedValue);
          Storyboard.SetTargetName(FlipBack, strBackSelectedValue);
          Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(FlipFront, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));
          Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(FlipBack, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));
          SplineDoubleKeyFrame sFlipFront = new SplineDoubleKeyFrame();
          SplineDoubleKeyFrame sFlipBack = new SplineDoubleKeyFrame();
          sFlipFront.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
          sFlipFront.Value = 0;
          sFlipBack.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
          sFlipBack.Value = 1;
          FlipFront.KeyFrames.Add(sFlipFront);
          FlipBack.KeyFrames.Add(sFlipBack);
          sbFlip.Children.Add(FlipFront);
          sbFlip.Children.Add(FlipBack);
          sbFlip.AutoReverse = true;            
          sbFlip.Completed += new EventHandler(this.sbFlip_Completed);      
          sbFlip.Begin();
```

Where i'm going wrong???

Comment: 1st. Which line does it throw the error on. 2nd. Create that in XAML. Stop creating crap in the code-behind!

Comment: 1. This error thrown at the last line. 2. Since i need n number of storyboards i cant do that in xaml. Thats y i moved to codebehind.

Comment: You can have n number in XAML. Whatever you can do in the code behind you can do in XAML. Make sure the storyboard is in a UI control (Window, UserControl) and pass in `this`... `sbFlip.Begin(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow got the answer.I have to convert the string to a image and pass to the function and then add to the target and now the flip of the image happens.

.cs Page:

```
Storyboard sbFlip = new Storyboard();
          sbFlip.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
          DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames FlipFront = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
          DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames FlipBack = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
          Storyboard.SetTargetName(FlipFront, strFrontSelectedValue);
          Storyboard.SetTargetName(FlipBack, strBackSelectedValue);
          Storyboard.SetTarget(FlipFront, imgFront);
          Storyboard.SetTarget(FlipBack, imgBack);
          Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(FlipFront, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));
          Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(FlipBack, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));
          SplineDoubleKeyFrame sFlipFront = new SplineDoubleKeyFrame();
          SplineDoubleKeyFrame sFlipBack = new SplineDoubleKeyFrame();
          sFlipFront.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
          sFlipFront.Value = 0;
          sFlipBack.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
          sFlipBack.Value = 1;
          FlipFront.KeyFrames.Add(sFlipFront);
          FlipBack.KeyFrames.Add(sFlipBack);
          sbFlip.Children.Add(FlipFront);
          sbFlip.Children.Add(FlipBack);
          sbFlip.AutoReverse = true;            
          sbFlip.Completed += new EventHandler(this.sbFlip_Completed);      
          sbFlip.Begin();
```

// Passing the string and find as image

```
Image imgBack = FindControl<Image>((UIElement)Layout, typeof(Image), strSelectedimg);
```

// Function to find image

```
public T FindControl<T>(UIElement parent, Type targetType, string ControlName) where T : FrameworkElement
       {

           if (parent == null) return null;

           if (parent.GetType() == targetType && ((T)parent).Name == ControlName)
           {
               return (T)parent;
           }
           T result = null;
           int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
           {
               UIElement child = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

               if (FindControl<T>(child, targetType, ControlName) != null)
               {
                   result = FindControl<T>(child, targetType, ControlName);
                   break;
               }
           }
           return result;
       }
```

// Adding these two lines in the funciton works

```
 Storyboard.SetTarget(FlipFront, imgFront);
          Storyboard.SetTarget(FlipBack, imgBack);
```